# The ways to avoid a numpy.stack FutureWarning?

Tags: python, numpy, stack

I'm trying to stack numpy arrays that are stored in a dictionary. So far, I found several ways to do this. Unfortunately, the most elegant code prints a FutureWarning:

```
sys:1: FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.
```

.

CODE EXAMPLE No.1 (doesn't give a warning, but is too cumbersome):

```
data_stack = np.stack([data_matrix[0], data_matrix[1], data_matrix[2], data_matrix[3], data_matrix[4], data_matrix[5], data_matrix[6], data_matrix[7], data_matrix[8], data_matrix[9], data_matrix[10], data_matrix[11]], axis=1)
```

.

CODE EXAMPLE No.2 (more concise and still doesn't give a warning):

```
data_stack = np.stack([data_matrix[key] for key in data_matrix.keys()], axis=1)
```

.

CODE EXAMPLE No.3 (this one I like the most, but it gives a warning):

```
data_stack = np.stack(data_matrix.values(), axis=1)
```

I have tried fixing this as follows:

```
data_stack = np.stack([data_matrix.values()], axis=1)
```

But this seems to break the code completely:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./CLN40ULPEF_PttV1350W1350G0000S0000T025.lib.py", line 261, in <module>
    data_stack = np.stack([data_matrix.values()], axis=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in stack
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 430, in stack
    axis = normalize_axis_index(axis, result_ndim)
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

.

Is there a (simple) way to make `data_matrix.values()` work with `numpy.stack` without giving a warning?

Comment: You could probably do `list(data_matrix.values())`, but of course any kind of operation adds computing time.

Comment: @mapf, adding `list` here doesn't hurt time.  `stack` iterates through all elements of the input argument, adding a dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj good to know, thanks!

Comment: Expanding a `dict.values()` to a full list is normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. A suitable answer is found in one of the comments by @mapf. Hence, I'm going to post it here as a final solution:

```
data_stack = np.stack(list(data_matrix.values()), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that `np.stack` does, after using the generator-warning function (`arrays = _arrays_for_stack_dispatcher(arrays, stacklevel=6)`) is:

```
arrays = [asanyarray(arr) for arr in arrays]
```

then it checks for matching shapes

```
shapes = {arr.shape for arr in arrays}
```

and expands the array dimensions

```
expanded_arrays = [arr[sl] for arr in arrays]
```

That's lots of list comprehensions.

Trying to save typing or time by passing the `dict_values` generator instead of a list, is a waste of your time and effort.

```
In [159]: adict.values()
Out[159]: 
dict_values([array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]]), array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])])
In [160]: list(adict.values())
Out[160]: 
[array([[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]]),
 array([[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]])]
```

Applying list to `values()` is normal Python3 practice.  For example you can't index the generator:

```
In [162]: adict.values()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-162-23f4ccd9e2f7>", line 1, in <module>
    adict.values()[0]
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable

In [163]: list(adict.values())[0]
Out[163]: 
array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
data_stack = np.stack([data_matrix[key] for key in data_matrix.keys()], axis=1)
```

you are iterating over keys of `data_matrix` `dict` and the retrieve value for each given key. You might simply iterate over values instead, i.e.:

```
data_stack = np.stack([v for v in data_matrix.values()], axis=1)
```

Comment: A comment suggested `list(dict.values())` which is basically the same thing.